# Writing a file to an internal storage on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, dynamic-analysis

I built an app that writes a file to a phone's internal storage. I have tested on my actual Android phone and it worked. I also tested it on Android Studio emulator running API 16 Google Nexus 4. Right now I am trying to run a dynamic analysis tool like Droidbox against my app but strange thing is every time I run the app inside an emulator with Droidbox, it doesn't create any file at all. It worked for both my phone and Android Studio but it doesn't do any for Droidbox emulator (which uses emulator from /android-sdk-linux/tools/ folder.) I have definitely included permissions and have set it the right Android versions. WHy is that I can't create a file under Droidbox?

Comment: Why do you need to run the emulation on droidBox. Any specific requirements??

Comment: I am actually in Cybersecurity class. I am supposed to use dynamic analysis tool to pull out information on the app. That's the main reason I am using Droidbox.